# 'this' returns undefined from a nested function

Tags: javascript, this

When I run the code below, the outputs will be:

1. john (expected)
2. undefined (WHY???)
3. 25 (expected)

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.getName = function() {
    const self = this;
    function run() {
      console.log(self.name); // output "john"
      return self.name;
    }
    run();
  };
  this.getAge = function() {
    return this.age;
  };
}

const john = new Person("john", 25); 
console.log(john.getName()); // output undefined
console.log(john.getAge()); // output 25
```

May

Comment: move `const self = this;` up to the `Person` function. `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Because you don't `return` the output of `run()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getName` function doesn't return a value.

```js
  this.getName = function() {
    const self = this;
    function run() {
      console.log(self.name); // output "john"
      return self.name;
    }
    return run(); // <- You need to return the value of run()
  };
```

Comment: Ah...I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!